# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result when trying to select from different tables

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to select 2 values from 2 different tables and getting this error. when i only selected from 1 table its worked. this is my code (after changing it already when looking on answers to this problem n line):

```
$apartmentNum = $_GET['apartmentNumber'];



$getBillsSumQuery = "SELECT a.totalBillsAmount , b.count(id) FROM apartments AS a , bills AS b WHERE a.number = "'.$apartmentNum.'" AND b.apartmentNumber = '.$apartmentNum.'";

$totalSum = mysqli_query($con,$getBillsSumQuery);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalSum); //this is where the program crushes

$newSum = $row['totalBillsAmount'];

$billsCount = $row['count(id)'];


echo '{"billSum":' . $newSum . ' , "billCount":' . $billsCount .'}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `count(b.id)` instead of `b.count(id)`. Use below query.

```
$getBillsSumQuery = "SELECT a.totalBillsAmount , count(b.id) FROM apartments AS a , bills AS b 
WHERE a.number = "'.$apartmentNum.'" AND b.apartmentNumber = '.$apartmentNum.'";
```

Comment: thank you i didnt noticed it. but its not the answer to my error, the problem still exists

Comment: Use join to connect 2 tables. @A.T